# How to convert string date in dateTime?

Tags: c#, windows

I have date in string format. I want to convert in date time in following format. I have referred few links but didn't get exact output.

```
String date = "03-23-16"; //MM-dd-yy
```

Requirement: it should be in date format like "March 23, 2016"

Can anybody suggest me how to convert this?

Comment: There's loads of articles on this, do google "Date formatting" and you shall find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert it to `DateTime` by using, say, `DateTime.ParseExact` and then convert it back to `string` using format `"MMMM dd, yyyy"`:

```
String date = "03-23-16"; //MM-dd-yy note that MM here
DateTime dtInstance = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MM-dd-yy", null); //this is how you convert string to DateTime
string newDate = dtInstance.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy"); //this is how you convert it back with format as you want
```

Also, note that `mm` is **minutes** format in `C# DateTime` while `MM` is **months**.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
string date = "01-08-2008";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("24/01/2013", "mm-dd-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

parse to string:

```
dt.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime.ParseExact("03-23-16", "MM-dd-yy", null).ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert it to Long Date Format by using *ToLOngDateString()*

```
 string date = "03-05-16";
 date = date.Replace('-', '/');
 DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
 string newDate = dt.ToLongDateString();
```

it will print :March, 03, 2016.